# Why does my C++/WinRT program with an IAsyncOperation take 2 seconds longer if I remove system("");?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-runtime, c++-winrt, winrt-async

I have written a short C++ program that uses the [WinRT Geolocation API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.geolocation) to print the user's location to the console. Here's a minimal working excerpt:

```cpp
#include <winrt/Windows.Devices.Geolocation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>

using namespace winrt::Windows::Devices::Geolocation;
using namespace winrt::Windows::Foundation;

IAsyncOperation<Geoposition> get_location() {
    Geolocator geolocator;
    co_return co_await geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync();
}

int main(void) {
    double lat, lon;
    {
        winrt::init_apartment();
        Geoposition pos = get_location().get();
        lat = pos.Coordinate().Point().Position().Latitude;
        lon = pos.Coordinate().Point().Position().Longitude;
    }
    winrt::uninit_apartment();
    printf("%.15g\n", lat);
    printf("%.15g\n", lon);
//    system("");
    return 0;
}
```

This program, compiled as written here, works (given the user has enabled desktop app access to location in their privacy settings), but about 80% of the time it waits for almost exactly 2 seconds after printing both lines but before exiting. I do not know if this pause is due to `IAsyncOperation`, `Geolocator`, or something else.

In the course of testing possible fixes, I have found that simply adding `system("");` immediately before the return statement seems to entirely eliminate the pause. Why is this? It feels like a hacky workaround; how can I address the underlying problem directly? Is there anything else I should do to pinpoint the issue?

Other things I've tried:

- Using `std::cout << pos... << std:endl;` makes no difference
- Adding `fflush(stdout);` makes no difference
- Replacing `printf("%.4f\n", pos...)` with `printf("%.4f\n", 0.1234)` makes no difference
- Removing the inner block in `main()` eliminates the pause
- Running in `cmd` vs `powershell` vs `wsl` makes no difference
- Building with `/Od` vs `/O2` makes no difference
- Building for x86 vs x64 makes no difference

I am compiling with `/std:c++20` in Visual Studio 2022 17.8.6 using C++/WinRT 2.0.240111.5.

Comment: You never initialized COM before starting, and you never uninitialized it when finished. I suspect COM is trying to do emergency cleanup during those 2 seconds, and cleaning up while inside the loader lock is hitting a deadlock situation.

Comment: @RaymondChen I am not sure how to do that properly. I tried adding `winrt::init_apartment();` at the top of `main` and `winrt::uninit_apartment();` immediately before returning, but there is still a 2-second pause after the uninit.

Comment: A deleted comment asked about profiling. VS's built-in profiler appears to indicate the program uses 12ms (48 samples @4000/s) of CPU time over 2 seconds of being open. 46 samples are right at the beginning, then there's one [System Code] and one `ntdll.dll` > `__scrt_common_main_seh` > `ucrtbase.dll` at the very end. I don't know how to find more useful information from the profiling. In any case, the CPU is barely active during that time.

Comment: Break into the debugger during the 2 second pause to see what the process is doing.

Comment: @RaymondChen The debugger has helped me figure out that the pause occurs after `return` (??) - if I set a breakpoint on the closing brace of `main()`, the pause happens after stepping past it, at which point the program and debugger exit. At the breakpoint, in addition to the main thread, there are 7 `ntdll.dll` threads, stack frame `_NtWaitForWorkViaWorkerFactory@20`, and one `combase.dll` thread, stack frame `_NtWaitForMultipleObjects@20`. Everything I see looks the same as if I add the `system("");` line. This is far deeper into C++ debugging than I've been before. What else can I do?

Comment: `// L0` is an odd way to construct a coroutine promise. At least here, this isn't required. `// L2` reads awkward, too. I believe the `Close()` method should be called only if you are interacting with an `IAsyncOperation` at the ABI. The C++/WinRT projection should be taking care of that for you already. Just replace `L0-L2` with `auto const pos = get_location().get();` and things should just work. Given your debug information, however, I will not be surprised if your code hits a genuine bug in C++/WinRT's async implementation.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the hang. Note that even though you are calling `winrt::uninit_apartment()` at the end, you failed to clear out all your COM references before uninitializing COM, so COM is still going to be doing "emergency cleanup". You need to destruct your `getLocation` and `pos` (which are COM objects) before uninitializing COM. One way is to move those variables to an inner block (so they destruct at the inner close-brace) and uninitializing COM after the close-brace. Another way is to use an RAII type to manage COM initialization.

Comment: Which version of C++/WinRT are you using?

Comment: You'll need to move the `uninit_apartment()` call out of the scope. Otherwise, the WinRT object destructors run *after* COM has already been uninitialized on the calling thread.

Comment: @IInspectable @RaymondChen Thank you both for the tips. I've edited the code slightly to be more in line with your advice (I think - please let me know if I got something wrong). I tested with the latest stable version of C++/WinRT as of now, 2.0.240111.5. It still hangs for 2 seconds about 80% of the time (same as before), and adding `system("");` still fixes it.

Comment: @IInspectable Moved `uninit_apartment()`; thanks. Also updated Visual Studio to latest just in case. The delay still exists, unfortunately

Comment: Update: I think the important part of `system("")` is that it causes `cmd /c` to run. Replacing `system("");` with `_spawnl(_P_WAIT, "C:\\Windows\\system32\\cmd.exe", "/c", NULL);` prevents the pause. Using e.g. `C:\\Windows\\system32\\rundll32.exe` instead of `cmd.exe` does not prevent the pause. Unsure how to dig deeper than this or if it's even helpful to do so.

Comment: What version of Windows? The fact that you have a call stack with combase  suggests that COM is not yet fully uninitialized.

Comment: @RaymondChen I've tested identical binaries on 5 PCs now. The 3 Windows 10 (Home and Pro, 19045.3930) systems consistently do not pause; the 2 Windows 11 (Home, 22621.3007) systems consistently do. Compiling on a fresh install of VS on Win10 did not give different results across the 5 systems.